# When was the first manned rocket-propelled plane launched?

Tags: aviation-history, rocket

I believe that it's an issue of some interest in the history of aviation.

Comment: please define the parameters of "rocket"

Answer (score 1):

There's an interesting text on the subject, freely available in the internet (in German) by Austrian rocket pioneer Max Valier. https://booksc.org/book/80611012/6a4e2a [From his book 'Raketenfahrt',  München / Oldenbourg, 1930]

Valier gives extensive and valuable details on the rocket-powered glider that was possibly the first rocket-propelled vehicle to become airborne, but he also mentions a semi-legendary account of a Chinese attempt, centuries ago, by a mandarin Wan-Hu... (page 236).

A fragment of Valier's text:

[image]

Abundant details on that rocket plane follow...

Comment: rocket propelled != rocket. this is the reason the community closed the previous question. it needs more details, the definition of "rocket" that qualifies is not provided